# use css to make object appear, then after delay, make it disappear

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using css to make an image appear after a certain delay time. I want to make it disappear after another delay time. I have the appear part working, but once I add the disappear part, neither of them work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

html:

```
<img class="anim-object anim-smallcar bluebag" src="img/bluebag.gif" />
```

css:

```
.bluebag {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 160px;
    left: 42.25%;
    opacity: 0; 

    animation-name: opacityOn;
    animation-duration: 100ms;
    animation-delay: 13.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

    animation-name: opacityOff;
    animation-duration: 100ms;
    animation-delay: 17.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

}
@keyframes opacityOn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes opacityOff {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change I would make to Alexandre's code is to make the opacity keyframe all one thing like this:

```
@keyframes opacityOnAndOff {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50%{
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Depending on how long you want to spend on going to full opacity and then clearing out, you can change the percentages, so if you want a longer closing, you could change the code above to something like

```
@keyframes opacityOn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30%{
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add more CSS animation iterations while changing the value of your opacity on the @keyframes the 0% to 25% to 50% to 75% and finally 100%

```css
.bluebag {
    opacity: 0; 
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px; 
    animation: opacityOn 5s normal forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes opacityOn {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-object anim-smallcar bluebag" src="img/bluebag.gif">aa</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that ?

```css
.bluebag {
    opacity: 0; 
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px; 
    animation: opacityOn 1s normal forwards step-end;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes opacityOn {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-object anim-smallcar bluebag" src="img/bluebag.gif">aa</div>
```

---

CSS is not an iterative language. When you write that:

```
    animation-name: opacityOn;
    animation-duration: 100ms;
    animation-delay: 13.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

    animation-name: opacityOff;
    animation-duration: 100ms;
    animation-delay: 17.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

your second section override the first one.

Comment: Thanks for noting that it isn't iterative -- that explains my dilemma!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it resolves your problem.

Comment: It doesn't resolve my problem, but that insight is key.

Comment: The snippet does not reproduce the expected behavior ? Maybe i misunderstand. Didn't you want the bag to appear after a delay then disapear after another delay ?

Comment: Yes, I want it to appear after a delay, then disappear (not fade out) after another delay.

Comment: Oh ok, i've updated my answer. Just add at the end of the animation property `step-end`.